# Electron: Is there any way to access/modify a main process array over ipc

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, electron

In general, arrays passed over electron ipc was copied.

```js
// main process
global['test'] = []
// renderer process
console.log(remote.getGlobal('test')) // []
remote.getGlobal('test').push('1')
console.log(remote.getGlobal('test')) // expected: ['1'], actual: []
```

But modify object would work well.

```js
// main process
global['test'] = {a: 1}
// renderer process
console.log(remote.getGlobal('test')) // {}
remote.getGlobal('test').a += 1
console.log(remote.getGlobal('test')) // expected/actual: {a: 2}
```

To be able to directly modify array from main process on renderer process, I tried to pass a Proxy which wrapped an array in main process:

```js
// Main Process Code
const real = []
global['proxy'] = new Proxy({}, {
  get: (_, property) => Reflect.get(real, property),
  set: (_, property, value, receiver) => Reflect.set(real, property, value, receiver),
  deleteProperty: (_, property) => Reflect.deleteProperty(real, property),
  enumerate: (_) => Array.from(Reflect.enumerate(real)),
  ownKeys: (_) => Reflect.ownKeys(real),
  has: (_, property) => Reflect.has(real, property),
  defineProperty: (_, property, descriptor) => Reflect.defineProperty(real, property, descriptor),
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor: (target, property) => {
    let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(real, property)
    if (descriptor) {
      descriptor.value = real[property]
      Reflect.defineProperty(target, property, descriptor)
    }
    return descriptor
  }
})

// Renderer Process Code
const proxy = remote.getGlobal('proxy')

proxy.push(1) // error thrown: Uncaught TypeError: proxy.push is not a function
console.log(proxy.join(','))
```

As expressed in the code comments, it seems that there is a problem of value passing with proxy. In this case, is there any other effective and practical way to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. First Main Process:

```
//global array
global.test = {
 myarr: [3]
};

//...electron setup: window etc...

setTimeout(function() {
 console.log(global.test); //now shows 3 and 6
},5000);
```

In the renderer (e. g. index.html script):

```
var remote = require('electron').remote;

var _old = remote.getGlobal('test').myarr;
_old.push(6);

remote.getGlobal('test').myarr = _old; //update global with altered array

console.log(remote.getGlobal('test').myarr); //now shows 3 and 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my purpose is not to manually assign the new array to the old one. therefore I use proxy.

Comment: @Plutonist What's wrong with reseting the array? Essentially it's the same as your proxy workaround (just a lot less code). Also, consider changing the question then, because for Q "Is there any way to modify a main process array over ipc" you got the correct answer.